# How to SELECT * and rename a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can easily select all my columns from a table with:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
```

But if I want to rename the column `bar` in `foobar`, I need to specify all the fields manually. This make my query not robust if a new column is added to the table:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,bar AS foobar FROM foo
```

Is there a possibility to write something like

```
SELECT *, bar AS foobar from foo
```

Comment: Yes... did you try running it?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu nothing wrong with using select *. Its maybe not optimal in all cases but saying one should NEVER use it just wrong.

Comment: Why dont you just rename the column with an alter?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, why? Isn't a good way to be protected if the database is updated?

Comment: @nowox Using `SELECT *` is a surefire way to *break* a script if the table is updated...

Comment: @Jakob Well, I wish I can do this. I cannot touch the structure of my horrible database :(

Comment: Select * is fine for debugging, testing, evaluation purposes or information gathering as far as embedding it in production code, I wouldn't recommend it...-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select  If you need all the columns of the table query the information_schema to get the listing so you don't have to retype them all.

Comment: You mean "This makes my query robust if a new column is added to the table"!

Comment: Here are some ideas as to [why you shouldn't use `SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: @Jakob you are right, i'll clean up my comments. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: @Jakob To a rough approximation, one should never use `SELECT *` in a production environment.

Comment: How about building the query dynamically by fetching the list of columns from system tables and preparing the SELECT statement? In this case you can add aliases to columns dynamically and build the result-set you need.

Comment: Could you do this in only one SQL statement?

Comment: Not sure, at list I can put all the logic into the single sp where I can pass the table name, schema name, the list of source columns that need to be changed and the corresponding list of columns with the alias names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can do the following:

```
SELECT  bar AS foobar, a.* from foo as a;
```

But in this case you will get bar twice: one with name `foobar` and other with bar as `*` fetched it..

Comment: You answer is nice but as you said I will get the column twice. So I guess I will wait a bit for another answer

Comment: there is no other possibility as * always fetch all the columns..
and in that case you can't change name in simpler queries..
if you are going to use some case or anything else then it will slow down..

Answer (score 3):

There's not really a great way to get at what you're after. Typically, best practices dictate that you should avoid `SELECT * ...` for performance reasons. Especially for the reason you just specified - say you add a large field to this table that is irrelevant to the query at hand. You're still retrieving the data with a "*" whether you need it or not.

As for your query, you *can* do `SELECT *, bar AS foobar from foo` - but you'll be duplicating your results, as you'll return the original column by name as well as a column with your new alias.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Normally most table colums are not important for a select statement.
I had different cases in the last 10 years and most of 60% oft colums were unused.

In our times performance is one of last challenges for developers.

Please test in every case with Explain MySQL command for performance of statements.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.